# Discord.js bot Send a message to specific channel in every server it's in

Tags: discord.js

I've got this so far:

```js
function dailylot() {
    let channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "general69420")
    if (!channel) {
        return;
    }
    channel.send(".")
    return;
}

function settimer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        settimer()
        dailylot()
        console.log("Cycle")
    }, 5000)
}
while (i < 1) {
    console.log("set timer " + i);
    settimer()
    i++;
}
```

Doing this works but only for the guild the message is sent in. Even once removing the `while` loop so it activates multiple times, it just wants to go to 1 guild only. How can I retrieve the channels of all servers? `bot.guilds.channels` isn't a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wold need to iterate over each of the guilds in your bot and get the channels for each of tem, this is the case because different from `message` or `guild`, `guilds` is not a class, meaning it doesn't have properties like `guilds.channels`, it is a collection of other guild classes.

This is an example on how to access those channels individually:

```
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
        // Use the channel for whatever you need
    })
})
```